# RESTful implementation for "archiving" an entry

Tags: restful-architecture

Say I have a table for `machines`, and one of the columns is called `status`. This can be either `active`, `inactive`, or `discarded`. A `discarded` machine is no longer useful and it only used for transaction purposes.

Assume now I want to `discard` a machine. Since this is an entry update, RESTfully, this would be a `PUT` request to `/machines/:id`. However, since this is a very special kind of an update, there could be other operations that would occur as well (for instance, remove any assigned users and what not).

So should this be more like a `POST` to `/machines/:id/discard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a strict REST perspective, have you considered implementing a `PATCH`? In this manner, you can have it update just that status field and then also tie it in to updating everything else that is necessary?

References:

https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/09/05/patch 
http://jasonsirota.com/rest-partial-updates-use-post-put-or-patch

Answer (score 0):

I think the most generic way would be to POST a Machine object with `{ status: 'discarded' }` to `/machines/:id/`.

Personally, I'd prefer the `/machines/:id/discard` approach, though. It might not be exactly in accordance with the spec, but it's more clear and easier to filter. For example, some users might be allowed to update a machine but not "archive" it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think post should be used when the resource Id is either unknown or not relevant to the update being made.

This would make put the method I would use especially since you have other status types that will also need to be updated

path

```
/machines/id
```

Message body

```
{"status":"discarded"}
```